# Batch, multiple conditions

Tags: batch-file

I have made this batch script in order to display files of subdirectories from current directory and also specifying a directory that I don't want to look into:

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%d in (.) do if not "%%~nxd"=="folder1" 2>nul dir /b /a-d "%%d"
```

But I would like to specify several "forbidden" directories. But something like:

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%d in (.) do if not "%%~nxd"=="folder1" && if not "%%~nxd"=="folder2" 2>nul dir /b /a-d "%%d"
```

Does not work. Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using the find command? It already provides functionality to recursively list all files. I assume that there is some parameter for exclude as well.

Comment: `if /I not "%%~nxd"=="folder1" if /I not "%%~nxd"=="folder2" ...`